# How to add arrow icon with CSS Entities and make it responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing the below HTML with Bootstrap 4 and I am stuck in one element part of the HTML.

Here is a preview of the design:

[image]

**HTML**:

```html
<section class="hm_sc_1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters p-5 align-items-center" style="background: #a4186c;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 text-center ">
                <img src="images/4632.png" alt="img-fluid" class="p-3 w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 p-5">
                <h4 style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
                    fugiat atque dolores cum nesciunt.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters p-5 align-items-center" style="background: #f6e1ec;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
                <img src="images/54332.png" alt="img-fluid" class="p-3 w-75">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                <h4 class="pt-0 pr-4 pb-4 pl-5" style="font-size: 20px; color: #251F3B;">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
                    consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, labore. Quidem quasi officiis</h4>
                <div class="pt-0 pr-4 pb-4 pl-5">
                    <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #251F3B;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Est provident quisquam praesentium esse explicabo porro sed aperiam unde natus fuga
                        expedita cupiditate, at numquam animi quos nihil, itaque molestias! Eveniet!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can use the pseudo element to create the arrow.

Comment: either a pseudoelement or svg pathing

Comment: But how to place an arrow at bottom of the col?

Answer (score 0):

i add class called `"custom-down-arrow"` for down arrow using ":after" and css for it.

```css
.custom-down-arrow:after {
    bottom: -22px;
    left: 150px;
    border-width: 11px;
    border-color: #a4186c transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.custom-down-arrow {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="hm_sc_1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="custom-down-arrow row no-gutters p-5 align-items-center" style="background: #a4186c;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 text-center ">
                <img src="images/4632.png" alt="img-fluid" class="p-3 w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 p-5">
                <h4 style="font-size: 20px;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
                    fugiat atque dolores cum nesciunt.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters p-5 align-items-center" style="background: #f6e1ec;">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
                <img src="images/54332.png" alt="img-fluid" class="p-3 w-75">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                <h4 class="pt-0 pr-4 pb-4 pl-5" style="font-size: 20px; color: #251F3B;">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
                    consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, labore. Quidem quasi officiis</h4>
                <div class="pt-0 pr-4 pb-4 pl-5">
                    <p style="font-size: 16px; color: #251F3B;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Est provident quisquam praesentium esse explicabo porro sed aperiam unde natus fuga
                        expedita cupiditate, at numquam animi quos nihil, itaque molestias! Eveniet!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```